# How to visualize radar data on Rviz

Tags: ros

I am new to **ROS** and I would like to visualize my radar data on **rviz.**

radar massage is made in this way :

```
uint8 id

float32 distance_sd_m

float32 angle_sd_deg

float32 velocity_sd_m__s

float32 distance_m

float32 angle_deg

float32 velocity_m__s

float32 width_m

float32 length_m
```

Answer (score 0):

At lease by searching the wiki ;-)

you can find radar examples here [Ros Sensors](http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any standard way to do it. We ended up transforming radar ridings to point cloud and visualizing PC instead. It still does not show velocity though.